# Docker Python 32-bit

Tags: python, docker, 32-bit

I have a python code that works in a 32-bit python environment. I want to run it in a Docker container. How can I create a 32-bit python environment in a Docker container? Or does exist a Docker image with 32-bit python env?

Comment: IME Python code is usually pretty portable; what leads to the "32-bit" requirement?

Comment: There is a library that works only with Python 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but perhaps this might be help: https://hub.docker.com/r/clinstid/i386-python

It's referred to as 32-bit with Python 3.5 but the architecture is stated for `linux/amd64`, which is confusing.